# Pandas: Loop Through List And Find Word From List in Column ... Create New Column With Found Word from List

Tags: string, list, pandas, find, conditional-statements

I have a list shown below:

list = ['dog', 'cat', horse', 'bird']

I have a sample dataframe below.  I want my code to say: If TEXT contains a word in your list then create a new column called EXTRACT that picks out the key words and puts them in the new column.

```
ID  TEXT               
1   hello you person    
2   you have a dog     
3   the bird flew      
4   the horse is here  
5   bird bird bird
```

Below is my desired dataframe:

```
ID  TEXT               EXTRACT
1   hello you person    
2   you have a dog     dog
3   the bird flew      bird
4   the horse is here  horse
5   bird bird bird     bird
```

I know a non-efficient way to do this using syntax like: if word in TEXT column, then put that word in a new column.  But my true dataframe has a LONG list of words and the above method is too tedious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using df.apply and set intersection to see which words appear in both the text column and the words list.

You need to consider what should happen when more than one of the words appears in the text column

```
def word_finder(x):
  df_words = set(x.split(' '))
  extract_words =  word_set.intersection(df_words)
  return ', '.join(extract_words)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'text' : ['hello you person', 'you have a dog', 'the bird flew', 'the horse is here', 'bird bird bird', 'dog and cat']})

word_set = {'dog', 'cat', 'horse', 'bird'}

df['extract'] = df.text.apply(word_finder)
```

Output

```
                text   extract
0   hello you person          
1     you have a dog       dog
2      the bird flew      bird
3  the horse is here     horse
4     bird bird bird      bird
5        dog and cat  dog, cat
```